# How to respond with the same header in Wiremock?

Tags: java, wiremock

I am using Wiremock Java API to create a stub for a REST HTTP service.
I want to make this stub "mirror" the header   in a response, i.e. put the same header and value that it got in a request.

The header is generated in runtime so, unfortunately, there is no way to put a static value with the method

```
.willReturn(WireMock.aResponse()
                    .withHeader(<key>, <value>)
```

Is there a way to achieve this with Wiremock?

Comment: The buzzword is `Request templating`. You can add some Java/.. classes which are working like a converter. Those are applying additional rules/Templates for reuqests. This will make wiremock be able to mirror special header/... on runetime and not require a static simple mapping. Check docs: http://wiremock.org/docs/response-templating/

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to do this is to [enable response templating](http://wiremock.org/docs/response-templating/) when you start WireMock then do something like this when configuring your stub:

```java
.willReturn(aResponse()
            .withHeader("My-Header-Key", "{{request.headers.My-Header-Key}}"));
```